# Lost most of the basic drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, package-management

Due to some Wifi connection issues, I followed an article for some troubleshooting, and without reading carefully -my bad- I ended up with a command (that I don't even remember) that deleted almost all important drivers on Ubuntu (including display, network, multimedia and some others).

Now I have no internet connection, and I want to restore all the drivers. I only have another laptop with internet connection and I have a usb, so what I am doing is that I install a package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and I copy the package to the broken machine and install it from the Ubuntu software center. The problem is that the installation never completes and gives an error due to uninstalled dependencies. And each package has a long list of dependencies.

So my question is: is there any other way to restore the lost drivers? or if there is a way to have the package with its dependencies all together in one file.

Comment: Afaik there is no utility that can recover a broken installation short of reinstalling on top of an existing installation. Thus, you may need to reinstall, and then make sure to NOT format partitions. This may work especially if you reinstall the version you had installed,  and if you haven't done much of other "special system improvements".

Comment: Are the debs for linux-image still present in /var/cache/apt/archives/ ?

Comment: Reinstall and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @chili555 what can i do with them ?

Comment: @PandaLion98 I am about to reinstall. Unfortunately I will lose all the installed applications.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image `uname -r`
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

Your drivers, etc. should be restored to default.

Comment: It gave me this error : package linux-image has no candidate unable to locate package -r and the debs exist normally.
I had to reinstall Ubuntu unfortunately, thanks anyway.